# How to unrar with the ESXi Shell?

Tags: shell, vmware, esxi, vsphere, unrar

I have root acces on a vmware vsphere esxi shell

just downloaded a bunch (108) sequence (parts) RAR files and need to unrar these.
apt-get install or yum and so don't work to install unrar.

How can I unrar with the esxi shell?

Comment: why downvoting this question?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off-topic for SO.

Comment: you can download and use rar directly from: https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, ESXi has *tar* only. Unrar the files on your own box and move them to the ESXi.

Comment: this seams indeed to be a fact